# Loop breaking in quick-sort algorithm

Tags: c#, sorting, for-loop, nested-loops, break

Implement quick sort algorithm with faulty results. Details of what I want to do can be found at the video: https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:HarvardX+CS50+X/courseware/cdf0594e6a80402bbe902bb107fd2976/22251a2b00ac42788c70ca6f6ccbe7fd/ Does break command take me out of inner loop or both loops? Below you'll find the code, any help will be welcome.

```
int main (void)
{

// Array of integers to be sorted
int list[] = { 3, 9, 8, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1};
int arrayIndexLimit = (sizeof (list) / sizeof (int)) - 1;
int temp = 0;

// "J" separates sorted part of array from unsorted one 
for (int j = 0; j < arrayIndexLimit; j++)
{

    // Find smallest value in unsorted part of array
    for (int i = j; i <= arrayIndexLimit; i++)
    {

        // Put smallest value in jth position 
        if (list[i] < list[arrayIndexLimit])
        {
            temp = list[j];
            list[j] = list[i];
            list[i] = temp;
            break;
        }  

        // Pivot (last item of array) is the smallest
        if (i == arrayIndexLimit)
        {
            temp = list[i];
            list[i] = list[j];
            list[j] = temp;
            break;
        }
    }

// Print sorted list
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`break` will only break you out of the current loop and return control to the outer loop

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4.aspx)

Comment: @Pilkington: Thanks for the patience for explaining this pretty basic question. So, after break, outer loop regain control and increment j, in this case, right? Best,

Comment: @MarcelloScattolini Correct

Comment: @MarcelloScattolini can you please explain how linking to MSDN from SO makes MSDN article so much easier to understand? (you did read the article before asking the question, didn't you?)

Comment: @Levenkov: Would you please clarify what is MSDN and SO? Thanks!